# UILabel is not resized in view after calling sizeToFit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel that is declared as an IBOutlet. After calling `sizeToFit`, I still do not see the entire text as there were not changes to the size of the UILabel. Then I did a check using `_myLabel.frame` and I found that the height was actually increased, but it is not reflected in the view. I tried to do the same thing by inserting the UILabel programatically and `sizeToFit` seemed to work perfectly.

```
[_myLabel setText:@"very very very long text"];
[_myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(_myLabel.frame));  //before sizeToFit
[_myLabel sizeToFit];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(_myLabel.frame));   //after sizeToFit
```

I'm suspecting it has something to do with auto layout.

Comment: What’s the line `[_myLabel setFrame:_descriptionLabel.frame]` supposed to do there?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I removed that line, it is not supposed to be there.

Comment: Where do you call the sizeToFit in the view controller, e.g. viewDidLoad, etc?

Comment: Can you show your constraints? specially the ones related to `myLabel` in the vertical dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the constraints. Thank you!

I fixed it by clearing the constraints and added this line:

```
    _myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = [_myLabel alignmentRectForFrame:_myLabel.frame].size.width;
```

to force the label to readjust it's height.

Answer (score 0):

Or, subclass `UILabel` and override `sizeThatFits:` to define what you mean by `sizeToFit`.